# Time difference not working when year changes

Tags: php, ajax

I have a script that was working, well is working but not properly. The function is suppose to work out the time difference between two dates/times.

The First date is the Current Date and Time (Date + Hr:Min) and the second date is chosen by a user.

The purpose is to show error when the current date/time is within 24 hours from the user chosen date. i.e. if today is 23/20/2012 16:00 and the user chooses 24/10/2012 15:00 (this mean its within 24 hours) but if user chooses 26/10/2012 19:00 then its passed 24 hours.

Now this works fine but when the date changes its year (when user selected any date after 31st Dec 2012.. it assumes its still within 24 hours.. and im quite baffled how this happens.. can anyone shed some light what I've done wrong?

```
    $dt = $_GET['dt']; $tm = $_GET['tm']; 

    // Current Date an time (Hrs & Mins)
$date1 = date("Y-m-d H:i");

    // Chosen Date/Time

$date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( "$dt" ) );
$diff = strtotime($date2." $tm") + - strtotime($date1);
if($diff/3600 < 24)
    echo "0";
else
    echo "1";
```

The following is the corresponding Ajax that makes th call

```
function getAjaxTime()
{

xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlHttp==null)
  {
  alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
  return;
  } 
dt = document.frm.arrival_date.value;
tm = document.frm.arrival_hour.value +':'+document.frm.arrival_min.value;
xmlHttp.open("GET","<?php echo $base_dir;?>/admin/get/timediff.php?dt="+encodeURI(dt)+"&tm="+encodeURI(tm),false);
xmlHttp.send(null);
return xmlHttp.responseText; 
}
```

Comment: the $_GET['dt'] you are passing must be some formatted date user entered (by JS plugin or not, that doesnt matter), just debug it when year switched and tell us what you see in this variable, this must strtotime() doesnt recognize the format.

Comment: `strtotime($date2." $tm") + - strtotime($date1)`... not exactly the most readable code.

Comment: Serg - I know what your saying, initially the dt and tm arent formatted variables. but $date2 formats the dt and diff formats tm. tm originally outputs as 06:00 (without format) then added to the strtotime to format it with the date.. is guess this is wrong way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
function isDateWithin24Hours($targetDate, $currentDate = 'now') {   
    $targetDate = new DateTime($targetDate);
    $currentDate = new DateTime($currentDate);
    $interval = $targetDate->diff($currentDate);
    //%a = total number of days
    if ($interval->format('%a') > 1) {
        return (int) false;
    }

    return (int) true;
}

echo isDateWithin24Hours('2012-10-24 19:00:00');

echo isDateWithin24Hours('2012-10-24 19:00:00', '2012-10-23 18:00:00');
```

Comment: So would 1 day = 24 hours according to the above script.. and would 26 hours come under 2 days?

Comment: 26 hours interval would = 1 if interval formatted as `%a`.  TIAS: http://codepad.viper-7.com/HtSiSR

Answer (score 0):

According to the php manual - https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php - your date is not a valid format:

```
24/10/2013   // with / as deliminators
```

These would be valid

```
24-10-2013   // with - as deliminators
10/24/2013   // with / as deliminators and as m/d/Y
```

---

Update-

Also, the following format is invalid in `strtotime` & `date`-

```
Thursday, 10 May, 2012 00:30
```

But this would be valid -

```
Thursday, May 10, 2012 00:30
```

---

Update #2

In fact once your `$_GET['dt']` is in a valid php format, you could simplify your code to-

```
$dt = $_GET['dt']; $tm = $_GET['tm']; 

// Current Date an time (Hrs & Mins)
$date1 = date("Y-m-d H:i");

$diff = strtotime($dt." ".$tm) + - strtotime($date1);
if($diff/3600 < 24)
  echo "0";
  else
  echo "1";
```

Comment: No, the date is actually shown like "Thursday, 10 May, 2012" when outputted

Comment: You posted that your user chosen date would be like `24/10/2012 15:00`. When you do `strtotime("24/10/2012 15:00")` nothing outputs, but when you change it to one of the valid formats `strtotime("24-10-2012 15:00")` or `strtotime("10/24/2012 15:00")` you get a valid time string returned.

Comment: Sorry, im passing the date to the dt variable without format like this "Thursday, 10 May, 2012".. and then im passing the time as "00:30"... then I try and format it.. how can I do the later efficiently?

Comment: `date("Y-m-d H:i")` is valid format. Sending `dt` in the format - `Thursday, 10 May, 2012` is invalid when sending to `strtotime`. If you send it as `Thursday, May 10, 2012` that would be valid, and it should fix your issue.

Comment: @Sean, I do not think that is accurate.  Either format is parsed just fine for me.  Tried 5.3, 5.4 stable and trunk.

Comment: Check out example #2 in the manual for `strtotime` - [http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). It is a great function to test if your date/string is valid when used in `strtotime`.

Comment: Jquery plugin passes me the date in this format so i just oassed it like that straight to PHP.. i tried everything to convert it wont allow me for some reason in jquery

Comment: @ficuscr - So `$date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( "Thursday, 10 May, 2012 00:30" ) );` works for you? When I run it, nothing returns. But when I do `$date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( "Thursday, May 10, 2012 00:30" ) );` it returns a date.

Comment: @Sean, I stand corrected.  With the time part on the string it does in fact fail to parse (returns epoch).  Without time part it does fine.

Comment: So okay, Iv got the date like this "Thursday, May 10, 2012" and Ive got time like this "00:00" What is the best way to add the two together to for ma date/time object?

Comment: If you got your date to `Thursday, May 10, 2012` then your code should work as `Thursday, May 10, 2012 00:00` is valid.